# MediaElement Source cannot be set after SaveState/LoadState

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

(**Note: All code has been severely simplified.**)

### Problem

MediaElement source not being set after Suspend/Resume. The CurrentState quickly changes to "Closed" after the source is set.

I am handling the MediaFailed event — it doesn't fire. I am also handling the MediaOpened event, which doesn't fire either.

### Details

I have the following method which updates the MediaElement's Source. It works really well as long as the app is **not** trying to resume after having been Suspended.

```cs
  private async void UpdateMediaElementSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var videoSource = this.DefaultViewModel.CurrentSource; // a string
     var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(videoSource);
     var videoStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

     this.videoMediaElement.SetSource(videoStream, file.ContentType);
     // The above line works many times as long as the app is not trying to Resume.
  }
```

When the app is Suspended it calls the **SaveState** method:

```cs
  protected async override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
  {
     pageState["MediaElementSource"] = this.DefaultViewModel.CurrentSource;

     // I also made the videoStream global so I can dispose it — but no dice.
     this.videoStream.Dispose();
     this.videoStream = null;
  }
```

When the app Resumes, it calls the **LoadState** method:

```cs
  protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
  {
     string source = string.Empty;
     if (pageState != null)
     {
        if (pageState.ContainsKey("MediaElementSource"))
        {
           source = (string)pageState["MediaElementSource"];
        }
     }

     var document = PublicationService.GetDocument(this.currentDocumentIdNumber);

     this.DefaultViewModel = new DocumentViewModel(document);
     this.DefaultViewModel.CurrentMarkerSourceChanged += UpdateMediaElementSource;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
     {
        // This causes the UpdateMediaElementSource() method to run.
        this.DefaultViewModel.CurrentSource = source;
     }
  }
```

I appreciate any help on this issue. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out that the mediaElement's Source was being set before it was added to the visual tree.

Usually, this is not an issue when doing this:

```
mediaElement.Source = whatever;
```

but it IS an issue when you do this:

```
mediaElement.SetSource(stream, MimeType);
```

### Conclusion

Make sure that your MediaElement is part of the VisualTree when you call SetSource(...).

A simple way to get my above code to work is by adding a global bool that is set to **true** once the `mediaElement.Loaded` event has fired. Then, inside the code that calls `SetSource()`, wrap that in an `if(_mediaElementLoaded)` block.