# Replacing a file previously used for source in MediaElement in Windows Phone 8.1 throws E_ACCSESSDENIED

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

What I want to do is to let user record his voice. The recording would be stored in local storage. User should be able to play the recording or replace it with a new one. And that's where I am having trouble.

Scenario A: there is no recording yet, this works fine... when user presses record button, these steps are taken to record the audio and then set it as source for media element.

```
// user starts recording by pressing a button 
// create file with replace option
var audioStorageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceIfExists);                
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(audioEncodingProperties, audioStorageFile); 
// user stops recording...
await mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync(); 
//...
audioStream = await audioStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
MyMediaElement.SetSource(audioStream, audioStorageFile.ContentType);
```

I can repeat this proccess as many times as I want and the old audio file is always replaced with the new one.

Scenario B: Recording already exists when I navigate to the page so I want to load it to the MediaElement right away (OnNavigatedTo event) like this

```
var audioStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(desiredName);
audioStream = await audioStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
MyMediaElement.SetSource(audioStream, audioStorageFile.ContentType);
```

So user navigates to the page and file is already loaded to the MediaElement. The problem starts when user wants to replace the old recording. This piece of code is called before the code from Scenario A:

```
MyMediaElement.Stop();
MyMediaElement.Source = null;
```

When it reaches the line

```
var audioStorageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceIfExists);
```

UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
It seems clear that the reason for the exception being thrown is that the file I'm trying to replace is in use. But I don't understand why and how to avoid it? Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out that the problem actualy was that I was setting the source of the `MediaElement` before the MediaElement was added to the visual tree. I moved the code to set the media source from `OnNavigatedTo` to `MediaElement.Loaded` event and the problem was solved. I found the solution thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405635/mediaelement-source-cannot-be-set-after-savestate-loadstate).

Answer (score 0):

Add .Source = null before you create the file

```
MyMediaElement.Source = null;
var audioStorageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceIfExists);
```

---

If you're not in the habit of closing/disposing your Streams after you are done...you going to have a bad time.

To make sure dispose gets called, get in the habit of using `using`

Set your `MediaElement` like so

```
var audioStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("your_wav.wav");
using(Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream audio = await audioStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    this.myMed.SetSource(audio, audioStorageFile.ContentType);                
}
```

---

Using the above methods, I was able to record over "your_wav.wav" no matter if it was already set as the Source of the MediaElement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your solution isn't working for me. when setting source in using statement, the `MediaOpened` event won't fire -> seems quite logical because the stream is disposed before the media is opened. Instead the `MediaFailed` event is fired with this code: `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D36C4`. Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202386/windows-8-app-mediaelement-not-playing-wmv-files). I think in this case the `MediaElement` should be responsible for closing the stream. I tried doing so myself in `MediaOpened` but didn't help

Comment: Interesting thing is that after I set the source with `SetSource` and the `MediaOpened` event is fired, the MediaElement.Source property is `null` despite the audio being loaded to the MediaElement (I can play it)

Comment: @stambikk I was able to play the file just fine.  Unfortunately, I'm no where close to a development computer to upload the sample app to OneDrive for you.  Plus it's 2AM, I should be asleep :)

Comment: Appreciate the effort! I just managed to get it to work, thanks anyway:)

Comment: @stambikk What part of the my solution did you have to changed?

Comment: Well what was causing the problem was the MediaElement not being added to VisualTree, see my answer below...Now that I've adjusted the code as described in the answer, both yours code with `using` and mine without it work the same.